# WebStorm TS: Show all unused functions / variables/ modules etc

Tags: typescript, webstorm, unused-variables

WebStorm can detect unused "items" like functions, variables or modules and gives you a fix advice (mostly to remove it). Now this feature is really nice but you have to be inside the file to get the hint. Obviously if you have a large code base with lots of refactoring, you'd like to get a list of all this unused "items".

Is there a way to display a full list of all unused "items" or fixing advises?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can get the list of unused items by:

> Code > Run Inspection by Name ... >

Here you can choose *Unused global symbol*, *Unused local symbol*, *Unused imports* ...

If you want to get the list of **all** fixing advises you can run:

> Code > Inspect Code...